# How to get quote Id using sales_quote_collect_totals_after events

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer, quote, sales

I have create a programmatically order. But when submit order sales_quote_collect_totals_after events fire before save collect totals.
Here is my code :

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
try {
$customer_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('customer_id');
$selected_product_details = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected_product_details');
$firstname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('firstname');
$lastname = $this->getRequest()->getParam('lastname');
$email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
$street = $this->getRequest()->getParam('street');
$mobile = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mobile');

if ($customer_id == '') {
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname($firstname)
            ->setLastname($lastname)
            ->setEmail($email)
            ->setPassword('123456');
    $customer->save();
    $customer_id = $customer->getCustomerId();
} else {
    $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customer_id);
}
$product_details = json_decode($selected_product_details, true);
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
// Start New Sales Order Quote
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId($storeId);
// Set Sales Order Quote Currency
$quote->setCurrency($order->AdjustmentAmount->currencyID);
// Assign Customer To Sales Order Quote
$quote->assignCustomer($customer);
// Configure Notification
$quote->setSendCconfirmation(1);
foreach ($product_details as $_products) {
    $productId = $_products['productId'];
    $qty = $_products['qty'];
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object(array('qty' => $qty)));
}
// Set Sales Order Billing Address
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData(array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '',
    'street' => $street,
    'telephone' => $mobile,
    'vat_id' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
));
// Set Sales Order Shipping Address
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData(array(
    'customer_address_id' => '',
    'prefix' => '',
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'middlename' => '',
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'suffix' => '',
    'company' => '',
    'street' => $street,
    'telephone' => $mobile,
    'vat_id' => '',
    'save_in_address_book' => 1
));

if ($shippingPrice == 0) {
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping')
            ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');
} else {
    $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
            ->collectShippingRates()
            ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
            ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery');
}

//Fire event sales_quote_collect_totals_after Before ->collectTotals->save();

$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));
$quote->collectTotals->save();

// Create Order From Quote
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$orderId = $service->getOrder()->getRealOrderId();
// Resource Clean-Up
$quote = $customer = $service = null;
$this->createOrderInvoice($orderId);

$message = $this->__('Ordered Created Successfully');
$success = 1;

//send mail when placing order
$order_mail = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$order_mail->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$order_mail->sendNewOrderEmail();

$result = array("success" => $success, "message" => $message, "order_id" => $orderId);
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

} catch (Exception $ex) {
      $message = $this->__('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
      $success = 0;
      $result = array("success" => $success, "message" => $message);
      $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

      return false;
}
```

Here is config.xml :

```
<modules>        
    <Assel_StoreOwners>            
        <version>0.1.0</version>        
    </Assel_StoreOwners>    
</modules>       

<global>        
    <blocks>            
        <storeowners>                
            <class>Assel_StoreOwners_Block</class>            
        </storeowners>         
    </blocks>        

    <helpers>            
        <storeowners>                
            <class>Assel_StoreOwners_Helper</class>            
        </storeowners>        
    </helpers>  

    <events>
        <sales_quote_collect_totals_after>
            <observers>
                <set_custom_discount>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Assel_StoreOwners_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setDiscount</method>
                </set_custom_discount>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_collect_totals_after> 
    </events>  
</global>
```

I have create a setDiscount function in observer.php
But When fire this events i have didn't get quote_id.

Here is observer.php code :

```
     function setDiscount($observer) {
            $quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $quoteid=$quote->getId();
            $customer_id = $quote->getCustomerId();
     }
```

when call this observer I have didn't get quote_id. But I have getting customer_id.

Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$quote->getEntityId()** to get the quote_id

Comment: Yes, I have tried $quote->getEntityId() but not success.

Comment: Does the order and quote are saved on the database?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding with your code,you are creating order programatically by adding and loading products,customer hence quote id is not generating.Since quote id is generated when a product is added to cart thats why you are not getting quote id.

Answer (score 0):

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

### $quote->getEntityId(); or $quote->getId();

```
 $quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                       $grandTotal = 0;
  foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
 //get all data here
                      }
```